# Why the navigation buttons suddenly stop working?

Tags: reactjs, button, navigation, slider, swiper.js

I have such a slider in my react project. I've customized the buttons. It was ok but suddenly the buttons stopped working. My Swiper version is 9.3.2. I tried use `SwiperCore.use([Navigation])` to solve the problem but it didn't help.
Would you please help me solve this problem?

````
export default function Upcoming({heading, color}) {
  const prevRef = useRef(null);
  const nextRef = useRef(null); 
  return (
    <div className="separate" style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
      <h1 className="pubsem">{heading}</h1>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
        onInit={(swiper) => {
          swiper.params.navigation.prevEl = prevRef.current;
          swiper.params.navigation.nextEl = nextRef.current;
          swiper.navigation.init();
          swiper.navigation.update();
        }}
        pagination
        spaceBetween={20}
        slidesPerView={3}
        breakpoints={{
          300: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
          },
          640: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
          },
          768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
          },
          1024: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
          },
        }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className="card swiper-slide">
              <div className="card-image">
                <img src={slide1} alt="public seminar" className="card-img" />
              </div>
           </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className="card swiper-slide">
              <div className="card-image">
                <img src={slide3} alt="public seminar" className="card-img" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className="card swiper-slide">
              <div className="card-image">
                <img src={slide2} alt="public seminar" className="card-img" />
              </div>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
<SwiperSlide>
          <div className="card swiper-slide">
              <div className="card-image">
                <img src={slide2} alt="public seminar" className="card-img" />
              </div>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper> <div ref={prevRef} className="swiper-navigation__prev">
          Prev
        </div>
        <div ref={nextRef} className="swiper-navigation__next">
          Next
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: I don't understand, but where do you assign links for prevRef, nextRef. They are NULL

Comment: These references are assigned to the Swiper component by accessing them in the onInit function. I should mention that neither my navigation nor my pagination works and so It shouldn't be a problem with buttons that customized.